# java eclipse windowbuilder keyPressed event does not fire

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, keypress, windowbuilder

I've got a problem with my program what I can't solve. I'm trying for hours and tried to google, etc... I've seen many programs, which is working, but I don't know why my solution does not. My goal (for now) is simple, I want to write to the cmd-line in case of a mouse click or a key press. The first one works, but the second is not. Can anyone tell my why?

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class test {

    private JFrame frame;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    test window = new test();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public test() {
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.getContentPane().addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("Mouse has clicked!");
            }
        });
        frame.getContentPane().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("A key has pressed.");
            }
        });
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

}
```

Comment: 1) For Swing, we typically use [key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather than the lower level `KeyListener`. 2) *"I'm trying for hours and tried to google, etc... I've seen many programs, which is working, but I don't know why my solution does not."* I'm having trouble understanding why in the 'many programs' you tried, you did not see that the component in question needs to both be focusable & have the input focus in order for a key listener to work. (Or that this is one of the problems that key bindings help us to solve!)

Comment: Did you tried `frame.add...Listener(...)` instead of `frame.getContentPane().add...Listener(...)`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, finally I had enough time trying to find the solution and now I'm discovered it. I do not know why, but it was not possible to add a keyListener to the JFrame. I could only add for a JButton or a JTextField, etc... This is strange for me, a little bit :c

Comment: *"I do not know why, but it was not possible to add a keyListener to the JFrame. I could only add for a JButton or a JTextField, etc... This is strange for me, a little bit"* It should not be, if you read & understood my comment from 2 days ago.